# Expected value of inverse distance between two 3D normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, distance, multivariate-normal-distribution

Consider two independent trivariate normal random variables $X$ and $Y$. The means are non-zero and the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrices are non-zero. $X$ and $Y$ does not follow the same distribution. What is the expected value $E\left[\lVert X-Y\rVert_2^{-1}\right]$, and how can it be derived?

Comment: This would be easy to estimate via monte carlo simulation, would that be enough for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for an analytical expression, which I have only been able to find with a diagonal covariance matrix.

Comment: Another question, do $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Comment: They are both normally distributed, but otherwise can have very different parameters.

Comment: "$\rho_{12} \neq \rho_{13}$" has nothing to do with "non-spherical".  By the way, "$\rho$" of $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong It might not have been the most precise explanation. The point I was trying to make was that the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrices of $X$ and $Y$ are non-zero. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: I felt your goal is too ambitious.  Even with the univariate case, I doubt if the analytical expression exists.  To begin with, have you used MC simulation to confirm the expectation really exists?

Comment: Because $Z=X-Y$ has a trivariate Normal distribution, you are asking for the expected reciprocal length of $Z$ (which exists and is finite, btw, provided $Z$ is not of rank 1 with zero mean).  Thus, the only parameters that matter are those of $Z.$  Do you have any restrictions on those?  That would help, because in general we cannot expect any simple closed-form solution, but some special cases are straightforward.

Comment: @whuber There would be no hard restrictions on $Z$ that I can think of. However in practice, more often than not the overlap between $X$ and $Y$ would be small (samples from $Z$ would often be much greater than any element of the covariance matrix).